# Audio File Meta Data in Android Studio

Tags: android

Can I use cursor to extract meta data from a single audio/video file in Android Studio?
Generally we use cursor with MediaStore to extract all audio or video files in storage in Android Studio. But here I want to extract meta data from a single file. Is it possible using cursor, if yes then how?

Comment: For extracting data you need to do a query().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the cursor but I extract metadata using the `MediaMetadataRetriever` method like this

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(yourPath);

    String albumName = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    String artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);
    String duration = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    String mimeType = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);
```

for more information, you can [see here official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)